# How to add a horizontal gap with a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, swingx

I have a JLabel (actually, it is a JXLabel).

I have put an icon and text on it.

`<icon><text>`

Now I wand to add some spacing on the left side of the component, like this:

`<space><icon><text>`

I DON'T accept suggestion to move the JLabel or add spacing by modifying the image.

I just want to know how to do it with plain java code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution!

```
setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The like this: is not very clear, but you can add spacing by adding a transparent border of a certain width to the label

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to push the label to one side of it's container, you can add a glue. Something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayoutManager(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);

panel.add(new JLabel("this is your label with it's image and text"));

panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Though your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to modify the preferredSize of the JLabel, you can use the [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) Manager to specify separations between components, you only have to use the GridBagLayout in the container and add the JXLabel to it with a [GridBagConstraints](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) object specifiying the insets to the left:

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JLabel label=new JLabel("xxxxx");

GridBagConstraints constraints=new GridBagConstraints();

constraints.insest.left=X; // X= number of pixels of separation from the left component

panel.add(label,constraints);
```

Note that i have omitted a lot of configuration properties in the setup of the constraints, you better read the documentacion of [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)